Задача с азбукой Морзе
Пользователь написал программу, которая должна переводить
цифры на язык азбуки Морзе, но она не работает.
Помогите исправить ошибку.
morze = {'1': '•----' ,
         '2': '••---' , 
         '3': '•••--' ,
         '4': '••••-' ,
         '5': '•••••' ,
         '6': '-••••' ,
         '7': '--•••' ,
         '8': '---••' ,
         '9': '----•' ,
         '0': '-----'} 
print(morze[int(input("введите цифру"))])

Пытался скобки поменять, не получилось. Не понимаю, в чем ошибка. После ввода числа выдает ошибку: KeyError: 1.

ключ - строка, тогда int не нужен

Если ключ словаря строка, то и обращаться к словарю нужно со строкой. Либо наоборот - поменяйте ключи на числа, а не строки. Но, наверное, лучше оставить строки, потому что вдруг у вас потом ещё буквы будут, а не только цифры.

Спасибо. Я и int убрал, и скобки квадратные и у меня ошибку выдавало все время. Спасибо

Убрал int, все заработало. Проблема была в квадратных скобках

morze = {
    '1': '•----',
    '2': '••---',
    '3': '•••--',
    '4': '••••-',
    '5': '•••••',
    '6': '-••••',
    '7': '--•••',
    '8': '---••',
    '9': '----•',
    '0': '-----'
}

digit = input("Введите цифру: ")
print(morze.get(digit, "Некорректный ввод. Введите цифру от 0 до 9."))


Хотя можно проще: result = morze.get(digit); if result: ...

Я вспомнила про  get. Это точно самый изящный вариант.

Да, так ещё короче, как сейчас ))  Хотя обычно результат всё-таки ещё для чего-то нужен дальше. Но тут можно так, красиво.
